# Submenus are not displayed correctly

Tags: css

I would like to have the same result as this example.

[image]

1. For the sub-menus (portfolio, contact, etc...): a background that takes the whole width.
2. The titles of the submenus are almost centered

In my sidebar, I have two rubrics: `Category` and `Markets`.

Here is my example...

[image]

My problem is that the width of the submenus (Portfolio, Contact, Indice, etc..) are not wide.
There is white to the left.

I would also like to center the menu subtitles like the example I showed you.

I made an illustration of the menu here -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/kora1348/exemple1?file=src/styles.css)

Thank you a lot for your help and your time.

***HTML***

```
<div class="sidebar" [class.sidebar-close]="!openSidebar" >
    <div class="logo-details">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/42/refj.png" /> 
    
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links" id="nav-links" >
      <li *ngFor="let item of menuSidebar" #itemEl routerLinkActive="active">
        <div *ngIf="item.sub_menu.length == 0" class="dropdown-title">
          <a [routerLink]="[item.link]">
            <i [class]="item.icon"></i>
            <span class="link_name">{{item.link_name}}</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.sub_menu.length > 0" class="dropdown-title" (click)="showSubmenu(itemEl)">
          <a>
            <i [class]="item.icon"></i>
            <span class="link_name">{{item.link_name}}</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu" [class.blank]="item.sub_menu.length == 0">
          <li><a class="link_name">{{item.link_name}}</a></li>
          <li *ngFor="let item_sub of item.sub_menu" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a [routerLink]="[item_sub.link]">{{item_sub.link_name}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

***CSS***

```
/* Sidebar */
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close {
  width: 60px;

}

.sidebar .logo-details{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .logo-details img {
  width: 37px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-3px);
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links > li {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
  background: #ffa726;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffa726, #ff5722);
}

/* Dropdown Title */
.sidebar .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.52s ease;
  /* */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 60px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #ffa726;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover i, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

/* a Tag */
.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Link Name */
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffa726;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover a .link_name, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active a .link_name {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li a .link_name {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Sub Menu */
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 70px;
  /* margin-top: -10px; */
  background: white;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
  color: #ffa726;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover a, 
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  display: block;
}

/* li:first-child contain .link_name */
.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child {
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child:hover .link_name, 
.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child.active .link_name {
  color: #ffa726;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px; */
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active .sub-menu.blank {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close ~ .home-section {
  left: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 70px left padding value in the element `.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu`, which is your `<ul>` element. This is being generated by this shorthand line of code for the padding values:

```
padding: 6px 6px 14px 70px;
```

You need to remove this 70px value and then just tweak the `padding-left` value of `.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li` which is currently set to 10px;

Answer (score 1):

Your `ul.sub_menu` tag has a padding of 70px on the left.

At the moment you have this CSS affecting it:

```
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
    padding: 6px 6px 14px 70px;
    background: white;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

If you just add a different higher priority CSS declaration that tells it to have a different padding on the sub menu, it should work.

Here is what it looks like with a 15px padding on the left:

[image: fixed example]

Also, I do see a CSS declaration that tells all `ul` tags to have a padding of 0. However, this is a lower priority than the mentioned code and gets overruled.